# ConversationAdded event is not fired when response group call arrives LYNC 2010 SDK

Tags: lync, lync-server-2010

I am trying to find out what event is fired when call arrives not to particular agent, but to the response group in which the user is registered. I am monitoring ConversationAdded event. In all cases when new conversation is added whether it is IM, audio call, or call from outside this event is fired. However when call arrives to the response group in which my user is also added, ConversationAdded event is not fired. May be there is a special event for the cases when call arrives to response group? However can anybody give a suggestion?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Regards

Gagik

Comment: Hello @ObjectX

as I am not sure why the event is not fired for your response group. I can ensure you that it is working for me. 

One of my clients reported this issue and I would like to ask you if you have made any progress since then?

Comment: Hello. It was year and a half ago. Now actually I don't work on LYNC. but here is discussion and I think you it may help you. "http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/1c894661-9cf5-42c1-a391-ea455abc65bd/conversationadded-event-is-not-fired-when-response-group-call-arrives-lync-2010-sdk?forum=communicatorsdk"